# Grails 4: Standalone port

Tags: spring-boot, grails

I'm using Grails 4.x and create a runnable war via

```
grails war
```

command. I can run it via

```
java -jar myapp.jar
```

I would like to change the port dynamically via parameter, and tried

```
-Dgrails.server.port.http=8083
```

but with no success. It still runs on default port 8080. Earlier with Grails 2.3.6, it worked with parameter port=808.

I cannot find anything in the documentation (http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Command%20Line/war.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign a value to the `server.port` system property, that value will be used.

```
~ $ grails -version
| Grails Version: 4.0.5
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_202
~ $ 
~ $ grails create-app sullivanportdemo
| Application created at /Users/jeffscottbrown/sullivanportdemo
~ $ 
~ $ cd sullivanportdemo 
sullivanportdemo $ ./gradlew assemble
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 19s
7 actionable tasks: 7 executed
sullivanportdemo $ 
sullivanportdemo $ java -jar build/libs/sullivanportdemo-0.1.war 
Grails application running at http://localhost:8080 in environment: production

sullivanportdemo $ 
sullivanportdemo $ java -Dserver.port=8084 -jar build/libs/sullivanportdemo-0.1.war
Grails application running at http://localhost:8084 in environment: production
```

Comment: Thanks, that works like a charm. Funny, I had it the other way around and this does not work:
java -jar myapp.jar -Dserver.port=8084